# The function strfind() in Octave is not finding double new line in a text file

Tags: string, octave

I am trying to execute a part of code in Octave that is supposed to find double line in a text file (.txt)

SO first the code get the file content:

```
fid = fopen(filename);
if fid
    file_contents = fscanf(fid, "%c", inf);
    fclose(fid);
else
    file_contents = '';
    fprintf('Unable to open %s\n', filename);
end

end
```

than I have this piece of code that is supposed to find any double line in the text and get rid of the part that's before the first double line ( which is the header)

```
hdrstart = strfind(file_contents, [ char(10) char(10)]);
file_contents = file_contents(hdrstart(1):end);
```

When I execute the second part, I get this error
**error: hdrstart(1): out of bound 0**

Which means my "hdrstart" vector is empty so the strfind() function is not finding any \n\n (which I know there is !)

Any ideas where the problem could be ? Thanks in advance for your support.

Edit:

It fails for this sample of text file:

"Header

this is the start of the core of the email
end of email"

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce with `file_contents = char([72 101 108 108 111 10 10 32 87 111 114 108 100]);` Using your `strfind`, I get `hdrstart = 6` as expected. Please post a small sample for which this fails.

Comment: Were you able or unable ?

Comment: I am reading a .txt file using the fscanf function. I am not the one producing the texts. those text files are spam emails that I want to remove the headers from.

Comment: sorry one more thing, when I  look for only one new line char[(10)] or I look for any other charter it works fine .it happens only for 2 new lines

Comment: I took the string I gave above, dumped it to a text file, cleared the variables from my workspace and ran your code. I still get `hdrstart = 6` as expected. I am **not** able to reproduce your error. Please provide a small sample for which this fails.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please see the small sample added above.

Comment: I get `hdrstart =  7` for your example. Perhaps your file has both CR **and** LF? Try this: once you've read `file_contents` into your workspace, type `file_contents - 0`. Subtracting zero from the character array converts it to numeric. Check starting at index 7 and see what values are there.

Comment: you're brilliant :) I tried it and I got starting from index 7: 13 10 13 10 .. is this how it expresses  2 new lines instead of 10 10 ?

Comment: It depends on the operating system. Windows uses CR/LF, Unix-type OS's use CR.

Comment: I see, thank you beaker for your help :)